# Suppose that $\text{rank}(T^{2}) = \text{rank}(T)$. Prove that the range and null space of $T$ have only the zero vector in common.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Suppose that $\text{rank}(T^{2}) = \text{rank}(T)$. Prove that the range and null space of $T$ have only the zero vector in common.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\ldots,\alpha_{n}$ be a basis for $V$, where $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\ldots,\alpha_{k}$ is a basis for the null space $N$ of $T$ and $T\alpha_{k+1},\ldots, T\alpha_{n}$ is a basis for the range $R$ of $T$. We must prove that $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{k},T\alpha_{k+1},\ldots,T\alpha_{n}$ are linear independent, which implies that $N\cap T = \{0\}$. Let us assume that $\alpha\in N\cap R$. Then we can express it in both basis: $\alpha = a_{1}\alpha_{1} + \ldots + a_{k}\alpha_{k}$ and $\alpha = a_{k+1}T\alpha_{k+1} + \ldots + a_{n}T\alpha_{n}$. Consequently, one has
\begin{align*}
& a_{1}\alpha_{1} + \ldots + a_{k}\alpha_{k} - a_{k+1}T\alpha_{k+1} - \ldots - a_{n}T\alpha_{n} = 0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& a_{k+1}T(T\alpha_{k+1}) + \ldots + a_{n}T(T\alpha_{n}) = a_{k+1}T^{2}\alpha_{k+1} + \ldots + a_{n}T^{2}\alpha_{n} = 0
\end{align*}

Since $\text{rank}(T^{2}) = \text{rank}(T)$, let $\beta_{k+1},\beta_{k+2},\ldots,\beta_{n}$ be a basis for $R(T^{2})$, from whence we get
\begin{align*}
& a_{k+1}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n}b^{k+1}_{j}\beta_{j} + \ldots + a_{n}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n}b^{n}_{j}\beta_{j} = 0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& (a_{k+1}b^{k+1}_{k+1} + \ldots + a_{n}b^{n}_{k+1})\beta_{k+1} + \ldots + (a_{k+1}b^{k+1}_{n} + \ldots + a_{n}b^{n}_{n})\beta_{n} = 0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& a_{k+1}b^{k+1}_{k+1} + \ldots + a_{n}b^{n}_{k+1} = \ldots = a_{k+1}b^{k+1}_{n} + \ldots + a_{n}b^{n}_{n} = 0
\end{align*}

Then I get stuck. If we prove that $a_{k+1} = a_{k+2} = \ldots = a_{n} = 0$, then $a_{1} = a_{2} = \ldots = a_{k}$, and $N\cap T = \{0\}$. Could someone help me to complete this demonstration or exhibit any theoretical flaw?

Comment: For your solution, note that most of your steps could have been done with $T = \frac{d}{dx}$ with $T$ being the vector space of polynomials with real coefficients.  You would need to extend your finite basis to an infinite one, but since you don't use the finite nature of your bases anywhere, there isn't any step in your solution that would fail with that extension.  Compare this to the proofs given in user744868's solution below, in which both have a crucial step requiring finite dimension.  (either "surjective implies injective" or the rank-nullity theorem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appreciate the enthusiasm with which you dove into this, applying definitions, and mucking in with bases. However, there's a key fact that I think you're missing, which simplifies things:
$$R(T^2) \subseteq R(T).$$
This is true for any operator $T$ (even nonlinear operators!), and can be proven in a single line:
$$v \in R(T^2) \implies (\exists w \in V)(v = T(Tw)) \implies v \in R(T).$$
Therefore, if we know that $\dim R(T^2) = \dim R(T)$, then these spaces must be the same, and $T|_{R(T)}$ (i.e. $T$ restricted to $R(T)$), is actually a surjective linear operator! As such, $T|_{R(T)}$ is injective (recall, surjective linear operators on finite-dimensional spaces are invertible), hence
$$T(a_{k+1} T v_{k+1} + \ldots + a_n T v_n) = 0 \implies a_{k+1} T v_{k+1} + \ldots + a_n T v_n = 0,$$
as required.

As I originally hinted in the comments, there's a slightly slicker way to do this using the rank-nullity theorem, and the dual observation
$$N(T) \subseteq N(T^2).$$
By the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim N(T^2) = \dim N(T)$, hence
$$N(T) = N(T^2).$$
If $x \in N(T) \cap R(T)$, then there exists some $v \in V$ such that $x = Tv$, but at the same time, $Tx = 0$. Thus $T^2 v = Tx = 0$, hence $v \in N(T^2) = N(T)$. Thus $x = Tv = 0$, as required.

Comment: Nice way to approach it. Thanks for the contribution.